# JSON Accessor in Laravel 5.2 pivot tables

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent, relation

I have 2 Models:

Mission and User Model.
The pivot table of this is mission_user.

In the mission model I have this function:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')
            ->withTimestamps()->withPivot('json');
    }
```

In the "json" column of mission_user there is the following content:

```
{"status":"not_confirmed"}
```

So if I get the data of a mission with related users (in ajax)
I want that this column will convert into json.
But How can I do this?

When I get the data of it I use this:

```
Mission::with('users')->find(1);
```

But in the json of the mission there is only a "string"
in the users->pivot->json field ...

I need to use an accessor for this pivot field.
Something like this:

```
function getJsonAttribute() {
    return json_decode($this->users->pivot->json);
}
```

But this will not work, because a mission can have x users ...
So - how can I get a json object in `mission->users[x]->pivot->json` and not a string?